# Flutter: OneSignal silent notification for android and IOS

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been following this [tutorial](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup) to implement the push notification in my flutter app. I am wondering if it is possible to implement a silent notification easily in flutter.

I came across some suggestions to implement separately in underlying platforms and invoke, however, due to lack of knowledge, i am facing problem to do so.

How can i implement this feature in platform and invoke in flutter? is there any other alternate solution to implement silent notification?

Thanks in advance.